ldd does not show libpthread
I'm trying to build an executable that links to libcrypto and libpthread. Both are specified as -lcrypto -lpthread (in that order) in the Makefile. I copied both the libraries to a library path and provided that path with -L. But, when I do ldd on the executable, libpthread is missing.
l
inux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff388ea000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007551a1e00000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007551a1a00000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007551a2317000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007551a26cb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007551a1600000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007551a2701000)

running nm on the executable shows that some pthread symbols are missing.
U pthread_attr_destroy@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_attr_init@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_condattr_destroy@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_condattr_init@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_condattr_setclock@GLIBC_2.34
                 U pthread_cond_destroy@GLIBC_2.3.2
                 U pthread_cond_init@GLIBC_2.3.2
                 U pthread_cond_signal@GLIBC_2.3.2
                 U pthread_cond_timedwait@GLIBC_2.3.2
                 U pthread_cond_wait@GLIBC_2.3.2
                 U pthread_create@GLIBC_2.34
                 U pthread_join@GLIBC_2.34
                 U pthread_mutex_destroy@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_mutex_init@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_mutex_lock@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_mutex_unlock@GLIBC_2.2.5
                 U pthread_sigmask@GLIBC_2.32

Output of readelf -d on the executable also does not list libpthread.
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcrypto.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]

Our software has a reference build on a RHEL machine. That build shows libpthread and some other libraries. Why won't it work on standard Ubuntu 24.04?

Which compiler are you using? At least with gcc, I think the recommended way to build with posix threads is to use the -pthread option for BOTH the compile AND link phase, rather than adding -lpthread to the link phase alone. Having said that, if the link phase succeeds then it must have resolved all the symbols that it thinks are referenced - what exactly doesn't "work"?

I want to understand why libpthread is missing from the ldd output and why nm is showing pthread symbols as undefined.
